# websocket paramiko Throw a socket.timeout exception

Tags: websocket, paramiko

Paramiko module always throws an exception

```py
paramiko.buffered_pipe.PipeTimeout
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_innerenter code here
    self.run()
  File "c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/index.py", line 42, in runenter code here
    data = self.chan.recv(1024)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\channel.py", line 685, in recv
    raise socket.timeout()
socket.timeout
```

I am building a webssh project using paramiko, websocket, xterm.js.

I tried Tornado and Flask but both throw an exception for socket.timeout

This is the Flask code

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_sockets import Sockets
import paramiko
import threading
import time
from gevent import pywsgi
from geventwebsocket.handler import WebSocketHandler


app = Flask(__name__)
sockets = Sockets(app)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True

HOSTS = "172.16.100.100"
PORT = 22
USERNAME = "root"
PASSWORD = "123456"


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    if request.method == "OPTIONS":
        response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "DELETE, GET, POST, PUT"
        headers = request.headers.get("Access-Control-Request-Headers")
        if headers:
            response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = headers
    return response


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, chan, ws):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.chan = chan
        self.ws = ws

    def run(self):
        while not self.chan.exit_status_ready():
            time.sleep(0.1)
            # try:
            data = self.chan.recv(1024)
            self.ws.send(data)
            # except Exception as e:
            #     print("异常信息", str(e))

        self.chan.sshclient.close()
        return False


@sockets.route("/terminals/")
def terminals(ws):
    sshclient = paramiko.SSHClient()
    sshclient.load_system_host_keys()
    sshclient.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    sshclient.connect(HOSTS, PORT, USERNAME, PASSWORD)
    chan = sshclient.invoke_shell(term='xterm')
    chan.settimeout(0)

    thread = MyThread(chan, ws)
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()

    while not ws.closed:
        message = ws.receive()
        if message is not None:
            chan.send(bytes(message, encoding='utf-8'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(
        ('0.0.0.0', 5000), app, handler_class=WebSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

This is the Javascript code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./xterm.css" />
    <script src="./xterm.js"></script>
    <script src="./fit.js"></script>
    <script src="./attach.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="terminal" style="height: 800px;"></div>
    <script>
        var term = new Terminal();

        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:5000/terminals/');

        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'), true);

        term.attach(socket, true, true);

        term.detach(socket);

        term._initialized = true

        term.writeln('Welcome to xterm.js');

        term.fit();

        // term.on('key', (key, ev) => {
        //     if (key.charCodeAt(0) == 13)
        //         term.write('\n');
        //     term.write(key);
        // });

        socket.onclose = function () {
            term.writeln("closed. Thank you for use!");
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

To be sure, the host SSH connection is normal.

When the connection is established, `data = self.chan.recv(1024)` is data.

Answer (score -1):

problem solved

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./xterm.css" />
    <script src="./xterm.js"></script>
    <script src="./fit.js"></script>
    <script src="./attach.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="terminal" style="height: 800px;"></div>
    <script>
        var term = new Terminal({cursorBlink: true});

        term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'), true);

        term.writeln('Welcome to xterm.js');

        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:5000/terminals/');

        term.attach(socket, true, true);

        term._initialized = true

        term.fit();

        socket.onclose = function () {
            term.writeln("closed. Thank you for use!");
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```